# Слово "пасека"

Tags: этимология

Для коров — коровник, для овец — овчарня, а почему для пчел — пасека?

Comment: Кстати, для собаки - конура, хотя для лошадей - конюшня. Видимо, есть два способа выбора наименования: от имени животного или от свойств самого "жилища". Кому - что, наверное, получилось случайно.  
Да, еще существует псарня, т.е. у собак есть и то, и другое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что пчел размещали там на открытой солнцу поляне в лесу, опушке, где вырублены (посечены) деревья. Первоначальное значение "лесная росчисть", а современное значение развилось потому, что пасеки ранее всегда устраивались на лесной росчисти

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то для пчел - улей. Что тоже непонятно...

Comment: Улей - индоевропейское слово с общим значением "полость", "трубка". Неудивительно, дикие пчелыы устраивают ульи в дуплах, естественных колодах.